# Is it bad to create functions in render?

Tags: reactjs

Is putting functions in render like this a bad practice?

Are these functions created every render, leading to a performance hit? How big of a performance hit? Is there a link somewhere that measures this or a reliable source saying that this is bad?

Does this cause unnecessary renders in any way? I hear this is especially not a good idea for `PureComponent`.

Having trouble finding clarification whether this is okay or not.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const myFunc1 = () => {};
    const myFunc2 = () => {};
    const myFunc3 = () => {};
    const myFunc4 = doSomething(() => {});

    return (
      <div>hello world</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes they will be re-created every time.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Do some profiling for your specific case if you want, if you have a component that re-renders at 60Hz then maybe it's not the best option.

Comment: In general it's not a great idea-why do they need to be created during render?

Answer (score 8):

> Is putting functions in render like this a bad practice?

Yep

> Are these functions created every render, leading to a performance hit?

Yes

> How big of a performance hit?

It can vary from totally negligible (most of simple components) to absolutely critical (if you constantly re-render your whole tree on a complex app).

> Is there a link somewhere that measures this or a reliable source saying that this is bad?

See [Chase DeAnda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849061/1380332).

> Does this cause unnecessary renders in any way? I hear this is especially not a good idea for PureComponent.

Indeed, since the function will be created at every render, if you pass them to a PureComponent, it will think the function changed and will render again.

> Having trouble finding clarification whether this is okay or not.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

More like a bad practice. It won't break your code, but can cause some serious performance issues. From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created
>   each time the component renders. In most cases, this is fine. However,
>   if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those
>   components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend
>   binding in the constructor or using the property initializer syntax,
>   to avoid this sort of performance problem.

So what you have in the example is fine because you aren't passing it down as a prop. If you passed `myFunc4` to the div as a prop, then you would see some performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

> Is putting functions in render like this a bad practice?

Well it certainly isn't *good* practice, but from a performance perspective it's entirely project-dependent.

> Are these functions created every render, leading to a performance hit? How big of a performance hit?

**Yes**, the functions are created on every `render` call, and if you are doing anything slightly more complex than this year's 600th job-search toy and you are calling your `render` repeatedly and rapidly (e.g. in a 60 FPS render cycle), the newly created function objects will have a *minor* impact on performance as the garbage collector will have to run more frequently.

---

*This is again project-dependent and opinion based, but we have a rule to prefer creating non-primitive objects outside any render calls (or any lifecycle methods that are directly associated with render, such as `componentDidUpdate`).*

---

> Does this cause unnecessary renders in any way?

Simply creating function objects inside `render` won't cause additional unnecessary renders by itself, but as I mentioned, the function objects are created with every `render` call, which can be more frequent than you might've expected at first.

If you are also passing down such a function object as a callback or handler to a child component, remember that `shouldComponentUpdate` implementations which do a shallow reference check on props will trigger, because with each render you are passing down a different function object reference.