# React: declare functions inside render bad practice benchmark

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, garbage-collection, benchmarking

According to the React community declare functions inside render method is a bad practice, as describe in this question: [Is it bad to create functions in render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848131/is-it-bad-to-create-functions-in-render)

For example:

```
export default function Clock({ time }) {
  const hours = () => time.getHours();
  const minutes = () => time.getMinutes();
  const seconds = () => time.getSeconds();
  const milliseconds = () => time.getMilliseconds();

  return (
    <h1>
      {hours()}:{minutes()}:{seconds()}.{milliseconds()}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

I can guess, the functions defined will be recreated after every render, forcing Garbage Collector to clean this memory-leak. But actually that is the function of the GC, so I'm not really sure if that is the main issue.

Since I can't find explicit documentation for describing **why** this is a bad practice I'm trying to create a benchmark to really test the performance, so I have created this two examples in codesandbox:

Bad practice:
https://codesandbox.io/s/render-with-function-inside-bad-practice-xx40g?file=/src/Clock.js

Good practice:
https://codesandbox.io/s/render-without-functions-good-practice-ckn1m?file=/src/Clock.js

I'm checking the react profiler but I can't really tell the difference, and using the performance tool of chrome I can see a difference in "scripting"

[image: bad practice performance]
[image: good practice performance]

But I don't understand what this means.

I'm not sure if I'm doing the benchmark properly

How could I improve this benchmark (in arrange or assertion) in order to really assest that using function inside render ends up in bad performance of the application?

Comment: ...what's the question?

Comment: Also note that the question you linked is about `class` components and the `render` method, but you're using a function component. It's actually **really common** to create functions inside function components. Yes, they do get recreated every time the function is called, but the overhead of that is **very** small; in the rare cases where you need to optimize to that degree, you can store them on a ref and only create them on mount.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my point is to really find Fact to really verify the assestment of being a "bad practice" with numbers, but so far the info I got was unconclusive to me

Comment: Creating the functions itself is relatively cheap, but passing it down as a callback via props may trigger unnecessary re-renders down the tree which is what is actually expensive and should be avoided by e.g. using `useCallback`. In your example the functions are independent of the component you creating them in so you could just pull them out of the component.